# GitHub Actions error: No OpenIDConnect provider found in your account for https://token.actions.githubusercontent.com

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, github-actions, amazon-iam

Here is the relevant portion of the yml file I'm using for GitHub Actions:

```
jobs:
  AssumeRoleAndCallIdentity:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Git clone the repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Configure AWS credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
        with:
          role-to-assume: ${{ secrets.AWS_ROLE_ARN }}
          role-session-name: GitHub_to_AWS_via_FederatedOIDC
          aws-region: ${{ secrets.AWS_REGION }}
```

This results in the following error in the GitHub Actions console:

```
Run aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
Error: No OpenIDConnect provider found in your account for https://token.actions.githubusercontent.com
```

However, I **DO** have an OpenIDConnect provider configured in AWS for `token.actions.githubusercontent.com`, and I have associated that identity provider in a trust relationship with the Role I'm using.

What could the problem be?

Answer (score 3):

Turns out Identity Providers in AWS IAM are case sensitive!  My Identity Provider was named like `token.actions.GitHubusercontent.com` because I copypasta'd from the [AWS documentation for connecting GitHub Actions to AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/use-iam-roles-to-connect-github-actions-to-actions-in-aws/) (see screenshot below).

[image: AWS documentation with wrong casing]

This doesn't work because it has different casing than what is expected by GitHub, which is `token.actions.githubusercontent.com`.

Comment: AWS - Please fix this typo in your docs!

Comment: For future readers, I'd recommend using [GitHub's canonical docs for AWS OIDC](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/security-hardening-your-deployments/configuring-openid-connect-in-amazon-web-services) rather than this AWS blogpost.